# What does it mean when I say that CDF is bounded away from 1?

Tags: mathematical-economics, probability

Suppose $\theta \in [\underline\theta, \bar\theta]$ is distributed with CDF F(.). What does it mean when I say that this F is bounded away from 1? Does it mean that F can never take the value 1 in this interval or that F never takes the value 1? What kind of probability distributions will act in this way?

Comment: The expression 'bounded away from' has a specific meaning in mathematics. For a definition you can look at these questions on Math SE https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1340637/what-does-bounded-away-from-zero-actually-mean

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1641798/sequence-bounded-away-from-0-and-2

Comment: Where is it from? How is it possible for a CDF to be bounded away from 1? Isn't $\lim_{x \rightarrow \bar \theta} F(x) = 1$ by definition? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does it mean that F can never take the value 1 in this interval or
> that F never takes the value 1?

In a sense yes, but it must be specified. Roughly speaking, it means that it is 'enough away' from $1$, but this statement must be made rigorous.

Observe that a function *bounded away from 'something'* is not the same as a *bounded* function.

A function is *bounded*, for instance *bounded above*,  if there exists a $M\in \mathbb {R}$ such that $f(x)<M$, for all $x$ in its domain. But a function can be *bounded away from 'something'* and be unlimited elsewhere.

I quote the clearest answer to MathES questions I reported in the comments (an accepted answer and with $27$ upvotes), which can explain better than I can do the concept (1):

> If a set $S \subset \mathbb R$ is bounded away from zero, it means that there
> exists $m > 0$ such that $|x| > m$ for all $x \in S$.
>
> If a function $f$ is bounded away from zero, it means that its range
> is bounded away from zero: there exists $m > 0$ such that $|f(x)| > m$
> for all $x$.
>
> **Edited to clarify:** When we say a set is bounded away from zero, we are not saying that away from zero, it is bounded. What would that
> even mean? We are saying that *its distance from zero is bounded below
> by a strictly positive number*. I see now that this is not
> self-evident, but that's what it means.

Of course, what @Varulle says (and Ishan Kashyap Hazarika
in the comments) is true, if $F$ is a CDF, it should be  $F(\bar {\theta})=1$ (and a CDF is always bounded).

So, it is necessary to read the paper you quoted to understand what the author means in that context. Maybe they uses a restriction of $F$? Why? Or a mistake? It is impossible to say anything without reading the original paper.

---

(1) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1340637/what-does-bounded-away-from-zero-actually-mean

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate the help! In the paper that I am reading, $\theta$ is a random variable that gets realized at t=2. Depending on a variable x, a particular value of $\theta$ is calculated at t=1, $\hat\theta(x)$ which is increasing in x. $F(\hat\theta(x))$ that is the probability that the realized $\theta \leq \hat\theta(x)$ is bounded away from 1.

Comment: I think it means that $\hat\theta(x)$ never takes the value $\bar\theta$. So instead of writing that the CDF is bounded away from 1, it should have been $\hat\theta(x)$ is bounded away from $\bar\theta$.

Comment: Your answers on this site are very helpful @BakerStreet!

Comment: Thank you very much @CormJack, you are very kind.

Answer (score 6):

This would mean that $\sup\{F(\theta):\,\underline\theta\le\theta\le\bar\theta\}<1$, which makes no sense as $F(\bar\theta)=1$.